# Cross Domain settings not working in IE10 - works in Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Our web portal requires cross domain working. The current version of the code works in IE (with an explicit HTML setting to emulate IE 7). The same code does NOT work in Chrome or Mozilla. When clicking on a link an error pops-up. It reads - *"An error has occurred:0 error filename=myfile.html"*.

I modified the JavaScript code as shown below.

```
//code for getting response from cross domain
$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
  }
});
$.get(
    'http://www.myportal.com/sierra/xxxx.html',
    function (response) {
        console.log("> ", response);
        $("#viewer").html(response);
});
```

This code works fine in Chrome and Mozilla, but does NOT work any more in IE. I then removed the HTML tag which was to emulate IE7 and replaced it with *edge*. Even then it did not work. It only started working after a few security settings were disabled. But the end users do not wish to change any browser settings only to access my web site.

Is there any other way which will work on all browsers for cross-domain access?

Comment: Can you please share us a JSFiddle link if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $.get(), use this javascript code:

```
function newReq(url,callBack)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XDomainRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XDomainRequest();
    xmlhttp.onload = function(){callBack(xmlhttp.responseText)};
}
else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
else
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        callBack(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```